# How to update model without updating created_at timestamp?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel has two timestamps on every table(created_at and updated_at).
I thought it would insert created_at at insertion of new row and update updated_at at update. However what happens is that created_at field is getting an update when I update my model.

How do I alter this behavior or what method should I use to update a row and just updated_at timestamp?
Right now I use `$model->save();`

```
 $point = Map::find($id);
        $point->longitude = $request->longitude;
        $point->latitude = $request->latitude;
        $point->description = $request->description;
        $point->save();
```

Comment: Would you please show me some of you code that you use for updating the model?

Comment: The code you've shown wouldn't be causing `created_at` to be updated on an existing model.

Comment: Do you have any mutators setup on your model which could be causing this?  For example a `setCreatedAtAttribute($value)` method?

Comment: No, all I have done was extending the model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.
I created created_at and updated_at columns manually and created_at had on Update assign current_timestamp attribute.